# Toggle Text With jQuery from css-tricks.com

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can't get the following code to work that I copied from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/toggle-text/.

Can you also explain the purpose of ':visible'.  Thanks.

Here's the fiddle and the code is copied below.

http://jsfiddle.net/thgv95da/

HTML:

```
<button id="more-less-options-button">more options</button>
```

JS

```
    $("#more-less-options-button").click(function() {
     var txt = $("#extra-options").is(':visible') ? 'more options' : 'less options';
     $("#more-less-options-button").text(txt);
     $("#extra-options").slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a `span` with id `extra-options` and now it works. Jquery checks if the content with id `extra-options` is visible if visible change the text and hide the `extra-options`

```js
$("#more-less-options-button").click(function() {
  
    var txt = $("#extra-options").is(':visible') ? 'more options' : 'less options';
     $("#more-less-options-button").text(txt);
     $("#extra-options").slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="more-less-options-button">more options</button>
<span id="extra-options">Text</span>
```

Comment: Thank you.  How would I modify the code to remove span ?  I don't need the span.  Just need the button to change its text when I push the button.

Comment: @Danny I don't exactly know how to edit this however i can give you a new one'

Comment: Thanks.  Can you create an alternate using `.toggle()` and the `var txt`?  (Not the deprecated version of `.toggle()`.)

Answer (score 2):

`:visible` looks for the element in html page with id `extra-options` but you don't have any.

I think you are looking for this: http://jsfiddle.net/g6r0c8j5/1/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `#extra-options` in the HTML.

[Here's a fork of your jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/202wgn19/)

Visible checks to see if the div is open or not, and the text changes accordingly.